# Using HTML DOM to change contents of Script Tag

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When we use html dom,we normally run code such as :

`document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = 'new text'`
to change the contents of a tag such as `<div>`

However I tried this with the `<script>` tag and it doesn't seem to be working. What should I try?

`document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0].innerHTML = "document.write('ok')"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a collection of scripts:

`var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');`

Executing `scripts[0].innerHTML = "document.write('ok')"` will effectively change the script's content, but the script's new content will not be executed.

The solution is straightforward:

1. Delete the script you want to update.
2. Create a new script and add it to the page's `body`. It will be executed.

With your to-be-updated script in the `body` this equals to:

```
document.body.removeChild(scripts[0]);
var newScript = document.createElement('script');
newScript.innerHTML = 'document.write("ok")';
document.body.appendChild(newScript);
```

Comment: Yes I realised that the code I wrote in the question would not execute, it was an example, and thank you for your solution.